# How can I get the current value of an object in another file?

Tags: perl

To summarize my problem, I'm not going to copy/paste the code but write a simple code.
I have 3 files, A.pm, B.pm C.pm.

**In A.pm A I have a class with a constructor:**

```
package A;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
  my $proto = shift;
  my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
  my $self  = {};
  $self->{NAME} = "Bob";
  bless ($self, $class);
  return $self;
}
```

**In my file B.pm, I have:**

```
package B;
use strict;
use warnings;
use A;
our $MyObjectA = new A();
sub myfunctionB {
 $MyObjectA->{NAME} = "Angel";
}
```

**In file C.pm :**

```
package C;
use strict;
use warnings;
use B;

sub myfunctionC {
   print("There is the name of my Object".$B::MyObjectA->{NAME}."\n");
}
```

**In the main p.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use B;
use C;

B::myfunctionB();
C::myfunctionC();
```

The results: the subroutine C print Bob, but I would like it to display Angel. How can I do?

Comment: Your code prints `There is the name of my ObjectAngel` as you requested. What more do you want?

Answer (score 3):

Before retrieving the object name, call `B::myfunctionB()`.

Comment: It would be too simple. I want the subroutine C to know that I have updated the value of the name in file C without telling him explicitly. May be I should change the reference. I don't know...

Comment: @A.Fab: Your subroutine `myfunctionC` just prints the current name field of the object. It doesn't need to "know" that it has been updated. Please be clearer about what you want

Comment: @A.Fab: Without calling myfunctionB, you haven't updated the value, you've only provided a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here seems to be that there is a CPAN module named [B](https://metacpan.org/pod/B). So to override loading that module in place of your own, you could put the current directory at the beginning of [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) by using the [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma:

**A.pm**

```
package A;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
  my $proto = shift;
  my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
  my $self  = {};
  $self->{NAME} = "Bob";
  bless ($self, $class);
  return $self;
}

1;
```

**B.pm**

```
package B;
use strict;
use warnings;
use A;
our $MyObjectA = A->new();

sub myfunctionB {
 $MyObjectA->{NAME} = "Angel";
}

1;
```

**C.pm**

```
package C;
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '.';
use B;

sub myfunctionC {
    B::myfunctionB();
    print("The name of my Object: "
          . $B::MyObjectA->{NAME}
          . "\n"
      );
}

1;
```

**p.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use C;

C::myfunctionC();
```

Output of running `p.pl`:

```
The name of my Object: Angel
```

Comment: I'm use to other languages and I am a beginner in perl.
I forgot to say that we call the functionB before the functionC. And I want C to know that I have updated the name value.

Comment: I have updated my topic, maybe it would be easier to understand.

Comment: @A.Fab Great.. I just tested your updated code and it outputs `Angel` not `Bob`. So I cannot see the problem. (Note: I had to add `use lib '.'` to load module `B` and not the core module also named `B`)